# How to prove this special inequality: $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac1{xy+z}>3$ for $\sum\limits_{cyc} xy=1$?

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$ s.t. $$\underset{cyc}{\sum} xy=1$$ Prove that $$\underset{cyc}{\sum}\frac{1}{xy+z}>3$$
I see that when $x=1,y\rightarrow1,z\rightarrow0$
$$\underset{cyc}{\sum}\frac{1}{xy+z}
 \rightarrow3$$
Thus the normal inequalities is  useless and I have tried the uvw method, but the solution form is too complicated.I want to know how to get rid of it.Thanks.

Comment: $1 = \sum xy = xy$ ?

Comment: What is the $\sum$ doing there?

Comment: Or do you mean x + y = 1?

Comment: Do you $\sum$ mean cyclic sum instead of ordinary sum?

Comment: he mean $xy+yz+zx=1$ and wants to prove $$\frac{1}{xy+z}+\frac{1}{yz+x}+\frac{1}{xz+y}>3$$

Comment: $\sum xy=xy+yz+zx$

Comment: @mathematicer Maybe you explicitly state in your question that you are taking a cyclic sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, we can assume that one term$\frac{1}{xy+z}\leqslant1$. 
That is$$xy+z\geqslant1=xy+yz+zx$$
Simplify it$$x+y\leqslant1$$
According to Cauchy inequality and AM-GM inequality$$\frac{1}{yz+x}+\frac{1}{xz+y}+x+y\geqslant\frac{4}{yz+zx+x+y}+x+y>\frac{4}{1+x+y}+x+y+1-1\geqslant3$$
So we just need $$\frac{1}{xy+z}\geqslant x+y$$
Replace $1$ by $xy+yz+zx$. The last equivalent to$$x+y\leqslant1\qquad\square$$

Answer (score 0):

The cyclic sum is defined as cycling the variables, thus

$$
\sum_\textrm{cyc} xy = \sum_\textrm{cyc} x^1y^1z^0 = x^1y^1z^0 + y^1z^1x^0 + z^1x^1y^0 = xy + yz + zx
$$

$$
\sum_\textrm{cyc} \frac{1}{xy+z} = \frac{1}{xy+z} + \frac{1}{yz+x} + \frac{1}{zx+y}
$$

We have

$$
xy+z(x+y) = 1
$$

so

$$
xy + z = 1 - z(1-x-y)
$$

thus

$$
\sum_\textrm{cyc} \frac{1}{xy+z} = \sum_\textrm{cyc} \frac{1}{1-z(1-x-y)}
\ge 3
$$

Comment: $z = \frac{1-xy}{x+y}$, not $\frac{xy}{x+y}$.

Comment: you are correct, I will correct that

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_\textrm{cyc} \frac{1}{1-z(1-x-y)}\ge 3$ (the very last step in your proof) ?

Comment: You are correct - this is not the correct proof...